# Importing a Promise Polyfill

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to use a [polyfill for promises](https://www.npmjs.com/package/es6-promise-polyfill)

The docs state I need to:

```
var Promise = require('es6-promise-polyfill').Promise;
```

But how can I import it ES6 style?

```
import Promise from ('es6-promise-polyfill').Promise;
```

The above fails.

Comment: Perhaps `import {Promise} from 'es6-promise-polyfill'`?

Comment: I'm afraid that does not work.

Comment: It's not an ES 6 module.

Comment: Further to @zeroflagL's point, if you are running in an ES6 environment, you shouldn't need the polyfill at all?